# When using snap to face, vertices on other side of mesh go to random positions and mesh becomes a crumpled mess

Tags: modeling

I'm new to blender and trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jmSgsaNSQ6s&t=1s), but the snap to face tool ends up making the mesh all crumpled and vertices go to random positions for no reason. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Any chance you could post a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: If you want help, you'll need to add a screenshot of your whole viewport :). My guess is *Proportional editing* set to *Random*